# How to change date format inside table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-date-functions

I want my DateOfBirth inside a Table to be displayed in dd/mm/yy format. I know we can retrieve dates in different format. But how could I change the format in the table itself?

Comment: You don't.  You store dates and times using native SQL data types.  Then you fetch them and use `date_format()` to get whatever format you want for presentation.

Comment: Please, do not save dates as varchar.

Comment: Storing a date in a non-MySQL date compliant format cannot be done on a date field.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you bother how it is stored? Just turn it to whatever format you need when retrieving it. If for some reasons you need a formatted version there just place it in a varchar column and apply custom format while inserting. Just mind that this way any date operations on it become harder and incredibly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70c23/1)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dates, '%D of %M, %Y') FROM datetbl;
```

Reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format